# How to keep pages with .html suffix in eleventy (static site gen) output?

Tags: static-site, eleventy

I have an existing oldschool, pure html static site I want to retrofit with an SSG, and I chose eleventy.

The site's structure is as such:

```
+ index.html
+ somepage.html
+ otherpage.html
```

As described on https://www.11ty.dev/docs/permalinks/#cool-uris-dont-change, eleventy will create:

```
+ index.html
+ somepage/index.html
+ otherpage/index.html
```

I don't want to change the (un)cool URIs I already have :-)

I understand I can add a .htaccess rewrite on the server to rewrite the URLs.

But isn't it possible to configure eleventy so it keeps the exact structure of the old site? I'd think so, but didn't find it in the docs.

Answer (score 4):

This has been answered by pdehaan on https://github.com/11ty/eleventy/issues/913 with a link to https://github.com/pdehaan/11ty-dynamic-permalink-test/

.eleventy.js

```
module.exports = (eleventyConfig) => {
  return {
    dir: {
      input: "src",
      output: "www"
    }
  };
};
```

src/pages/pages.11tydata.json

```
{
  "permalink": "{{ page.fileSlug }}.html"
}
```

This is the source directory structure

```
src/
└── pages/
    ├── index.html
    ├── otherpage.html
    ├── pages.11tydata.json
    └── somepage.html
```